# How do I load a .pgbackup file locally? with pgAdminIII?

Tags: postgresql

I downloaded a .pgbackup file but couldn't find information on how to load it into a local db. 
The forum I grabbed it from is not very responsive too.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`pg_restore` as per the docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgrestore.html)

You can use PgAdmin-III to restore a backup too, there's a "Restore" option in the menus. You have to select a database to restore into in order for this option to be enabled, or you can select the "postgres" database and check the option to create a new database for the restored DB in the restore options dialog.

It's also possible that you're dealing with an ordinary SQL dump. If so, you can load it with the command-line `psql` tool. There is no way I know of to restore an SQL dump via PgAdmin-III. Details of restoring backups with `psql` are discussed in the documentation.

I wrote a bit of a [rant about the usability of backup and restore in PgAdmin-III a while ago](http://blog.ringerc.id.au/2012/05/postgresql-usability-pgadmin-iii-and-pg.html).

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention this before but I tried this and when I were asked to select a backup file, it would recognize .dump files but not .pgbackup files. Selecting view all and then selecting the .pgbackup file didn't seem to help as the msg page didnt show any activity.

Comment: @RogerLam Could it be a plain SQL dump? Open the file in a text editor and see. The first 5 letters will be "PGDMP" if it's a custom-format backup for `pg_restore`; otherwise it's probably an SQL dump that's restored with `psql`.

Comment: Yea, the first 5 letters are "PGDMP".
I'm following the Matain a database object > Restore documentation but when I click display objects, I get about 15 error popups saying "Schema node not found for TABLE accounts [owner: spronk]" or similar errors. And when I click OK, it hangs.

Comment: @RogerLam Sounds like you need to create some users that the dump depends on first.